# jQuery: Loading an external page using AJAX, then calling insertAfter() into table row

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load some content into a table using insertAfter(), but the content I'm trying to load is html (output from an asp.net page) that I'm getting using AJAX.Load().

From my understanding, insertAfter() works like this: $("htmlcodehere").insertAfter("selector").  AJAX.Load() works like this: $("selector").load("Html/file").  How would I merge these two so that it loads the html (perhaps without adding it to any existing element?) then inserts that data using insertAfter()?

Bara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to explain me better with another answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //If you want to load it immediately. Anyway, you execute this code after an event
    $.get("file.html", //Make an ajax request to this file
          function(data){ //data is the file.html content
             $("table").append(data); //Or other operations like this to inject the html content into the table
          })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $.get or $.post to get the html and add a function on success that uses the insertAfter function to inject the code into the table

Comment: I tried something like this, but it's not inserting the html2 file into the right place.  In other words, how do I get it to insert in between the spans?

$("<tr class='addedrow'><td colspan='4' style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'><div><span></span></div></td></tr>").hide().insertAfter(row).load("/test2.html");

Bara

Comment: If you give the span an id, then you could use $("#spanId").html("htmlcode")

Comment: I don't know if i've understood what you want to do but if you want to add the html content beetween the spans you can do: 
$("<tr class='addedrow'><td colspan='4' style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'><div><span>"+data+"</span></div></td></tr>") 
where 'data' is the parameter, passed to the success function, that contains the ajax response

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, where would the htmlcode come from?  When is the ajax load being done?

Comment: @mck89: you mean after I call the load() I would go into the callback function, then use the response to insert it into the html?  Wouldn't that require me to insert the html being loaded somewhere first?  eg: $("some selector").load("htmlfile", function() { do insert after here }); .... that would mean I'd need "some selector" first?

Comment: The HTML code come from the file that you request with ajax. Using the $.get or $.post functions you can specify a function that will be executed when the request is complete, this function recive a parameter (the first) that is the html file source code, so inside this function you insert the first parameter (that contains html code) into the table

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery's $.get like this:

```
$.get("html/file", {}, function(obj) {
    htmlData = obj.data;
    $(htmlData).insertAfter("selector");
}, "html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help from mck89, this is what I ended up using:

```
           $.ajax({
              url: "/test2.html",
              cache: false, 
              success: function(data, data2) {
                 if (data2 == "success")
                 {
                    $(data).hide().insertAfter(row);
                 }
              }
           });
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Bara